# Add element to navigation property breezejs entity

Tags: angularjs, breeze

Well, I'm fairly new to both angular and breeze and I have an entity called `Collection` with a navigation property `products` since a collection can have many products in it.

So when I click a button I want to add that product to that collection but I haven't had any luck with it, I read breeze.js documentation and apparently doing something like

`collection.products.push(product)`

should work, but it's not working any thoughts on this?

this is the entity definition

```
  addType({
    name: 'Collection',
    defaultResourceName: 'collections',
    dataProperties: {
      id: { type: ID },
      name: { max: 255, null: false },
      slug: { max: 255 },
      productsCount: { type: DT.Int16 }
    },
    navigationProperties: {
      products: {
        type: 'Product',
        hasmany: true
      }
    }
  })
```

This is the code that actually tries to add the item to the products

```
function addToCollection(product){
  logSuccess('Product added to collection');
  //trying to put a product into the collection products, with no luck
  vm.collection.products.push(product);
}
```

And this is the template where the products are listed and the user can add them to the collection.

```
tbody
    tr(ng-repeat="product in vm.products | inCollection:vm.filter_by")
      td {{ product.master.sku }}
      td {{ product.name }}
      td {{ product.price | currency }}
      td
        img(data-ng-src="{{ product.master.images[0].mini_url }}")
      td.text-center
        .btn-group.btn-group-xs
          a.btn.btn-default(data-ng-click="vm.addToCollection(product)")
            i.fa.fa-plus
        .btn-group.btn-group-xs
          a.btn.btn-default(data-ng-click="vm.removeFromCollection(product)")
            i.fa.fa-minus
```

I've been debugging and breeze is not returning any goodAdds so it won't add it to the collection, any ideas on why this is not a goodAdd? BTW, collections N -> N products.

Comment: can you show me your code ?

Comment: I added some code, do you need anything else? thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Collection can have many Products and vice verse. If so, Breeze doesn't currently support what you're trying to do. You have to create a mapping table and break the relationship into 2 one-to-many relationships. See http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/presenting-many-many.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know breeze doesn't support modification through Navigation properties  So what you need to have is 2 types .. Collection and Property..

```
 addType({
name: 'Proeprty',
defaultResourceName: 'properties',
dataProperties: {
  id: { type: ID },
  collectionId: { type: int32}
},
navigationProperties: {
  collection: {
    type: 'Collection',
    isScalar: true
  }
}
 })
```

then when you want to add onto it you just make sure you set the collectionId 
Breeze's Navigation Properties aren't like typical relationships